# How to get a div scroll final value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to finish a Dynamically loaded div, I want JavaScript to get the final value when I drag the scroll bar, Not the all value of the scroll, This value can then be used to read the database.

I've tried scrollTop, and use addEventListener("mouseup", function(){...}), and it always outputs all values.
I tried to add some judgment, like sleep/wait, but it didn't work.

```
$().ready(function () {
    console.log("start...");
    var showItem = $("#showItem");

    showItem.scroll(function () {
        this.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
            readDB($(this).scrollTop(), "mouse");
        }, false);

    readDB($(this).scrollTop(), "scroll");
    });
});
```

```
readDB = function (height, desc) {
    console.log(height);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '/City/JsonActive?id=' + height,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (request) {
            console.log("Failed!");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Success!");
            // Append code...
        }
    });
}
```

I want to get the last location directly, as shown in the figure below, and then query the data for that location.

https://s2.ax1x.com/2019/04/23/EAgWFg.png

Now, It dispaly the value of every scroll / wheel. 
The picutre below is show the value by

```
readDB = function (height, desc) {
    console.log(height);  // I've already computed
    ...
```

https://s2.ax1x.com/2019/04/23/EA2EfH.png

Comment: I think you are looking for [scrollHeight](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrollheight.asp)...

Comment: What defines scroll is now finished.. Releasing the scrollbar on side? What about mouse scroll or keyboard. You would have to implement a wait time, but it's hard to say why your tries were unsuccessful with that.

Comment: @vaku  I've tried scrollHeight, but it looks like the total height, not useful for me.